# What info about the current item or workflow context is available in the CodeActivityContext object in a SP 2013 workflow custom code activity?

Tags: development, workflow-activity, workflow-manager

I am looking at creating a custom code activity for SP 2013 workflows (i.e. C# code that will be run by the Workflow Manager service), and then creating a custom workflow action for it to expose it in the SPD workflow editor UI.

I have found [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2012/SPC045) (relevant part starts at around 40 min.), and this [other example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/845039/creating-custom-code-activity-using-visual-studio-2013-workf/), which both explain how to:

- Create a new "Activity Library" project in VS.
- Add a new "Code Activity" item to the project, which gives you the class with the code that will execute when your activity is run.
- Pass various arguments (strings, `DynamicValue`s, etc.) in to the custom code activity through the `CodeActivityContext` object that is passed to the `Execute` method, where the values of these arguments are determined by parameters that are exposed in the sentence that is visible in the SPD workflow editor UI.

The example in the video is fairly self contained - it sorts an array that's passed in as a `DynamicValue`, and then returns that sorted array as another `DynamicValue`.

The example in the other link shows how you can interact with SharePoint using the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` CSOM, however, in order to initialize the CSOM `ClientContext`, *it uses a site URL (string) that is **explicitly** passed in as one of the defined arguments*.

My question is:

- is there anything about the current item or current workflow context (i.e., current list?  current web?, etc.) that is already included by default on the `CodeActivityContext` object passed to the `Execute` method?
- if yes, then how does one get to that information?

The [`CodeActivityContext` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.codeactivitycontext?view=netframework-4.8) seems pretty bare-bones and does not offer any clues, and the example provided by the default boilerplate code when you add a `CodeActivity` item to your VS project shows a weirdly self-referential way of getting data from the `CodeActivityContext` object by referring to it's own class property:

```
public sealed class TestCodeActivity : CodeActivity
{
    // Define an activity input argument of type string
    public InArgument<string> Text { get; set; }

    // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
    // and return the value from the Execute method.
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument

        string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);    // <-- that seems super weird to me

    }
}
```

So it's extremely unclear if that `context` object is carrying some default information about the current item or current workflow context, how one would access said data.